# Android Fragment cant change text language ,en to zh

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I'm using ViewPager inside fragment. The viewpager contains three fragments. My problem when I go back to this fragment i got a blank fragment .inner back press working good.

my code is following

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        //adapter.addFragment(new DiscoverFragment(), "Discover");
        adapter.addFragment(new TimelineFragment(), getString(R.string.home_nav));
        adapter.addFragment(new DiscoverNewFragment(), getString(R.string.discover));
        adapter.addFragment(new ServiceFragment(), getString(R.string.service));


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

   private void setupTabIcons() {

        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText(getString(R.string.home_nav));
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_binoculars, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabThree.setText(getString(R.string.discover));
        tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_group, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabThree);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText(getString(R.string.service));
        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_bell, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabTwo);


    }
```